# Chromium is corrupted after creating a desktop shortcut

Tags: chromium

I wanted to create the shortcut to a website on my desktop, so I dragged a bookmark from the bookmark bar of Chromium to the desktop. A file called `<name>` in the desktop containing the following text has been created:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=<name>
Type=Link
URL=<url>
Icon=text-html
```

I tried to double click on that file, and the page opened up correctly. After trying a few time I started getting a message about some wrong settings. After a few times the message stopped appearing, and I can't remember what was the exact content of the message. For a few minutes the error message would show up even when I was opening Chromium, without using that shortcut.

Now Chromium is not able to sign in to my gmail account and sync. If I try to set the password again, the settings page becomes gray and hangs.

What is broken in my Chromium?

EDIT:

After closing and reopening Chromium (without using that shortcut) the message came up again. This is its content:

```
Your profile could not be opened correctly.

Some features may be unavailable. Please check that the profile exists and you have permission to read and write its contents.
```

After starting Chromium I had 6 popups with this message showing up at the same time.

EDIT 2:

Chromium Version 28.0.1500.71 Ubuntu 13.04 (28.0.1500.71-0ubuntu1.13.04.1)

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the version number of Chromium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your question I understand that you had synced your account with google?

The simplest (though heavy handed) option will be to just delete your chromium profile. `~/.config/chromium`
try `mv ~/.config/chromium ~/old-chromium`. Now when you start chromium you will begin from a fresh profile where you can add your password and sync it afresh to your data with google.